# Send Scheduled Mailings Failure / CiviCRM Spark - Failing Job

Tags: scheduled-job, sparkpost, civicrm-spark

No scheduled mailings are sent, logs reporting:

```
Entity: Job Action: process_mailing
Summary" Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: Array ( [content] => Array ( [email_rfc822] => MIME-Version: 1.0 Subject: Thank you for attending Apereo's February's MicroCon (...)
```

Other errors include:

```
CiviCRM Spark - Failing Job 
Scheduled Job Send Scheduled Mailings is failing. Error was: Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Failure, Error message: Array ( [content] => Array ( [email_rfc822] => MIME-Version: 1.0 Subject: Thank you for attending Apereo's February's MicroCon (...)
```

Issues began after implementing Sparkpost.

Running CiviCRM v5.68.1 with SparkPost integration v1.8.0

Any advice on where to start appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to SparkPost support, the errors indicate possible email_rfc822 content issues. SparkPost suggested confirming if the email_rfc822 attribute is set in the content object of our transmission (i.e., within CiviCRM).

Documentation re. email_rfc822 attribute was provided:
https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/transmissions/#transmissions-post-send-rfc822-content

As the configuration was reviewed, it was discovered that a very silly but obscure config error on the server was the issue; when cron runs, it was ignoring some configurations and trying to use SparkPost's server.